# Do I have to change to AWS Pinpoint to use 10DLC for sending SMS messages or can I still use AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint

**Brief Description:**

What is an unregistered long code when it comes to an application sending SMS messages?

Plus, I'm using **AWS SNS** to send text messages through a node js application. Do I have to switch to **Amazon Pinpoint** to send to SMS messages?

**Detailed:**

I got an email from AWS saying that the `US telecom carriers would no longer support sending Application-To-Person (A2P) SMS messages over unregistered long codes`

It then says `If you are using long codes, Amazon strongly recommends that you complete the transition to toll free numbers, 10DLC, or short codes.`

In addition to that it appears that AWS wants me to use **Amazon Pinpoint** to send sms messages and email.  And the deadline to make the change is on June 1, 2021.

First off, whats an unregistered long code?  I imagine those are the long international phone #'s you'd see for someone in Europe or Latin America.  But to be sure I looked at AWS's docs and don't really see an example of one.

I have a node app running on an EC2 instance that uses **AWS SNS** to send messages to US text messages based off certain business logic.  The phone numbers in the config files have the following format: `US Country Code - 10 Digit phone Number` so an example is `+13215441222` which is a 10DLC plus the us country code.

In other words, my app is already sending text messages using 10DLC but its doing so using **AWS SNS**.  So do I even have to do anything that the AWS email recommends?

I don't have aws support to ask them this question so I'm asking it here.

Answer (score 1):

> In addition to that it appears that AWS wants me to use Amazon Pinpoint to send sms messages and email.

You can still use SNS to send SMS messages, either using 10DLC, short codes or toll-free.

> First off, whats an unregistered long code?

It is any number used in application-to-person (A2P) SMS messaging not registered with The Campaign Registry (TCR)

Let me quote documentation:

> In order to use a 10DLC number, **first register your company and create a 10DLC campaign using the Amazon Pinpoint (not Amazon SNS) console. AWS shares this information with The Campaign Registry, a third party that approves or rejects your registration based on the information.** In some cases, registration occurs immediately. For example, if you've previously registered with The Campaign Registry, they might already have your information. However, some campaigns might take one week or longer for approval. After your company and 10DLC campaign are approved, you can purchase a 10DLC number and associate it with your campaign. Requesting a 10DLC might also take up to a week for approval. Although you can associate multiple 10DLCs with a single campaign, you can't use the same 10DLC across multiple campaigns. For each campaign you create, you need to have a unique 10DLC.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities-10dlc.html

> So do I even have to do anything that the AWS email recommends?

Yes, you need to switch to 10DLC, toll-free or short codes.

Short codes reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities-short-codes.html

Blog post about 10DLC: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/provisioning-and-using-10dlc-origination-numbers-with-amazon-sns/